# How do I set the default value for a user entity reference field in hook_form_alter()?

Tags: entities, forms, 9

I tried the following code, but it doesn't work.

```php
$form['field_name']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#default_value'] = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
```

Answer (score 1):

The default widget used for the entity reference fields (with the exception of entity reference fields for taxonomy tags) is implemented by the [`EntityReferenceAutocompleteWidget`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldWidget%21EntityReferenceAutocompleteWidget.php/class/EntityReferenceAutocompleteWidget/9.2.x) class which, in its [`formElement()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldWidget%21EntityReferenceAutocompleteWidget.php/function/EntityReferenceAutocompleteWidget%3A%3AformElement/9.2.x) implementation, returns the following form element.

```php
$element += [
  '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
  '#target_type' => $this->getFieldSetting('target_type'),
  '#selection_handler' => $this->getFieldSetting('handler'),
  '#selection_settings' => $selection_settings,
  // Entity reference field items are handling validation themselves via
  // the 'ValidReference' constraint.
  '#validate_reference' => FALSE,
  '#maxlength' => 1024,
  '#default_value' => isset($referenced_entities[$delta]) ? $referenced_entities[$delta] : NULL,
  '#size' => $this->getSetting('size'),
  '#placeholder' => $this->getSetting('placeholder'),
];
```

Instead of `$form['field_name']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#default_value']`, the code should set `$form['field_name']['widget'][0]['#default_value']`.

```php
$form['field_name']['widget'][0]['#default_value'] = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
```

As side note, to alter the form element(s) returned from a field widget, Drupal uses [`hook_field_widget_complete_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_complete_form_alter/9.2.x) (and [`hook_field_widget_complete_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_complete_WIDGET_TYPE_form_alter/9.2.x)). It has access to the following information.

- The widget plugin instance (`$context['widget']`), which allows to access the widget ID (for example, *entity_reference_autocomplete*, *entity_reference_autocomplete_tags*) with `$context['widget']->getPluginId()`
- The field values (`$context['items']`), which allows to get the target type of the reference field (`$context['items']->getFieldDefinition()->getFieldStorageDefinition()->getSetting('target_type')`)or the field type (`$context['items']->getFieldDefinition()->getType()`), for example

When possible, it should preferable to use this hook for field widgets, instead of `hook_form_alter()`.

[`media_field_widget_complete_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21media%21media.module/function/media_field_widget_complete_form_alter/9.2.x) is the implementation of that hook done by the Media module.

Comment: are you sure that it should be `form['field_name']['widget'][0]['#default_value']`? Because according to https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/9.5.x/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Field/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/EntityReferenceAutocompleteWidget.php#L127 it should be an opposite: `form['field_name']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#default_value']`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is tagged for Drupal 9, but if anyone finds this page from Google looking for a **Drupal 7** solution, it took me about an hour of searching, but I finally found this:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    // .... //
    $whatever_node = node_load($whatever_nid);
    $form['field_event']['und'][0]['target_id']['#default_value'] = array ($whatever_node->nid => $whatever_node->title);
}
```

To clarify-- this is for when your entity reference is an auto-complete field.

This is for an Entity Reference, not a node reference.  Also, if you're doing anything to the title of the node in hook_node_load, make sure you are setting the original node title.